How to stop x tick labels from crossing x axis?
My x tick labels are crossing the x-axis into the chart area and I don't want them to, an example:

Another oddity is my x axis ticks stopped showing.
I've tried:

making ticks visible and,
adjusting the padding
trying horizontal alignment options

But the above did not solve my problem.  What should I try next?
Code used to create chart:
my_figure = plt.figure(**{'dpi': 100.0,
                          'edgecolor': 'black',
                          'facecolor': 'black',
                          'figsize': (8.0, 6.0),
                          'linewidth': 1.0})
ax = my_figure.add_subplot(111)
ax.bxp(**{'boxprops': {'alpha': 0.8, 'facecolor': 'C0'},
          'bxpstats': [{'label': 'obs5',
                        'mean': 74.00224000000001,
                        'med': 74.004,
                        'q1': 73.996,
                        'q3': 74.009,
                        'whishi': 73.984,
                        'whislo': 74.014}],
          'capprops': {'color': 'C0'},
          'patch_artist': True,
          'positions': [0],
          'showfliers': False,
          'vert': False,
          'whiskerprops': {'color': 'C0'},
          'widths': 0.5,
          'zorder': 1.0})
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(True)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', **{'bottom': False,
                                           'color': 'white',
                                           'direction': 'inout',
                                           'length': 3.0,
                                           'pad': 7.0,
                                           'top': False,
                                           'width': 1.0,
                                           'zorder': 1.0})
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelbottom=True)
ax.set_xticks(ticks=ax.get_xticks(minor=False),
              labels=['73.980', '73.985', '73.990', '73.995', '74.000', '74.005', '74.010', '74.015', '74.020'],
              minor=False,
              **{'alpha': 1.0,
                 'color': 'white',
                 'fontfamily': 'serif',
                 'fontsize': 'small',
                 'fontstretch': 'condensed',
                 'fontstyle': 'oblique',
                 'fontvariant': 'small-caps',
                 'fontweight': 'light',
                 'horizontalalignment': 'center',
                 'linespacing': 2.0,
                 'multialignment': 'center',
                 'rotation': 45.0,
                 'snap': True,
                 'verticalalignment': 'center'})
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(plt.NullFormatter())
plt.show()


the problem in your minimal code appears to just be that there is not enough space at the bottom of the plot. Any of the following will fix that: fig.tight_layout(), fig = plt.figure(layout="constrained"), fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2). That seems to be a separate issue to the tick labels overlapping the Axes, however, so you may need to dig a bit more in your original code to add the relevant parts to your minimal code.

having said that, my initial guess to fix your actual code would be to play with the horizontalalignment; e.g., something like: ax.set_xticks(ticks=ax.get_xticks(), labels=tick_labels, rotation=90, horizontalalignment="right")

@tmdavison, horizontalalignment is an excellenct suggestion, but I tried that - updated question to reflect that.   Will try your first comment in a few hours when I can.

@tmdavison, confirming fig = plt.figure(layout="constrained") worked as you suggested.  Also following your advice to dig deeper into original code.

@tmdavison, dug into original code to improve sample code, and it's exactly what's used to create figure displayed in question.  Thank you for improving my question asking ability.

Two things to change:

You currently set bottom=False in the first call to ax.tick_params. Setting that to True allows the ticks to be displayed on the x-axis.

To change the vertical alignment of the labels, set verticalalignment='top' in the call to ax.set_xticks. You currently have that set to center.



tested and works. verticalalignment='top' makes no sense to me, any insight on why top is what it is?  bottom seems more intuitive to me, my 2 cents.

It aligns the top of the text with the bottom of the tick. In the same way if you use horizontalalignment='right', it will align the right of the text with whatever position you are aligning to.
